# Getting Invalid redirect_uri using OAuth2 for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-sheets, bitbucket

I am not sure what to use as my Redirect URI. Bitbucket has a space for "Callback URL" which I am assuming is where it is entered. Anyone else have this problem/know how to use Redirect URI in this situation? I am setting up my service object below.

```
function getBitbucketServiceOAuth2()
{
// Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
// persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
// scope of the property store.
return OAuth2.createService('bitbucket')

  // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize')
  .setTokenUrl('https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token')

  // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
  .setClientId('WL6MQbGku7axd5kqun')
  .setClientSecret('jTRmqm5ug9fEUMAxeCQRx95uQz8LCevW')

  // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
  // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

  // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
 // .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')

  // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

  // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
  // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
  //.setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

  // Requests offline access.
  //.setParam('access_type', 'offline')

  // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
  // but not desirable in a production application.
  .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

And then getting the Authorize url below.

```
var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();

var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
  '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
    'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
var page = template.evaluate();

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error 403 (or equivalent), you will see "read more" link. Click on that and copy paste the expected link it gives. 
Now, use this link to generate new credentials in redirect uri.

This flow worked for me. Hope it works for you too.